# How-To change datables row color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have this datatable That I want to have different row color for each row, I am using the following code but the class is never added

```
var oTableNE = $('#tabelNE').dataTable({
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
        // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
        if ( aData[8] == "Submitted" )
        {
            $('tr', nRow).addClass("submittedColor");
            console.log("Change Color by adding CSS Class" + " nRow " +nRow + " " +aData[0] + " | " +aData[1] + " | " +aData[2]+ " | " +aData[8]);
        }else{
            console.log("Don't Change Color" + " nRow " +nRow + " " +aData[0] + " | " +aData[1] + " | " +aData[2]+ " | " +aData[8]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('tr:nth-child(' + nRow + ')').addClass("submittedColor");
```

Not sure what your are getting as nRow, if its the index of the row do as above. If its the row element itself do as below.

```
$(nRow).addClass("submittedColor");
```

Comment: nRow is an HTMLTableRow. nRow is part of datatables, first mehtod will not work, ill try the second method.

Comment: Yeah, the second method will work. $(nRow).addClass("submittedColor");

Comment: it works, but I still get the datatables CSS applied above my own class, that is I have two rules and datatables wins...

Comment: add a !important for your css rules

Comment: That works except for the order row... ill have to see how to overcome that one :) Thanks!